# Display custom information using GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I need to use `groupby` in my code to show `ActionId` and group based on the `controllerId` field.

The problem is, I except I can show `ActionId` with a select like this :

```
 var group = conList.GroupBy(x => x.ControllerId).Select(x=>x.ActionId).ToList();
```

But when I use the select it just shows me `Key` and `Count`.

this my code:

```
var group = conList.GroupBy(x => x.ControllerId).Select(x=>x.Key).ToList(););
```

How would I be able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on you question I did this:

Let's say that you have the following class:

```
public class Controller
{
    public int ControllerId { get; set; }

    public int ActionId { get; set; }
}
```

And the following data:

```
var list = new List<Controller>() 
{
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 1, ActionId = 1 },
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 1, ActionId = 2 },
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 1, ActionId = 3 },
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 2, ActionId = 4 },
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 2, ActionId = 5 },
    new Controller() { ControllerId = 2, ActionId = 6 }
};
```

What this command says is. Group my object of type *Controller* by ControllerId (the *Key*) and for each grouped item (g) I will have a list of type Controller.

```
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(x => x.ControllerId).Select(g => g);

foreach(var g in groupedList)
{
    //g --> is your grouped object a list of type Controller by unique ControllerId.
    //g.Key --> is the value of each unique ControllerId.        
    Console.WriteLine("Group: " + g.Key + " Actions: " + string.Join(";", g.Select(actions => actions.ActionId)));      
}
```

**Expected result**

```
Group: 1 Actions: 1;2;3
Group: 2 Actions: 4;5;6
```

You can test the code above [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aKmRUI).

I hope that explanation can help you out with your problem. Good luck!

[Here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea) you can find some samples and more explanation about `GroupBy` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/group-query-results).